# update Не обновляет , а удаляет строку в таблице в БД

Tags: php, javascript, sql, ajax

Есть такой ajax запрос

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
     $(document).on('click', '.update_b', function(){  


        $.ajax({
            url: "poseschenie_zanyatiy.actions.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                "ajax": "13",
                "id":$("#st_id_edit").val(),
                "st_each":$("#st_each").val(),
                "semestr_once_st":  $("#semestr").val(),
                "subject_once_st":  $("#subject").val(),
                "academicYear_once_st": $("#academicYear").val(),
                "lecturer_once_st":  $("#lecturer").val(),
                "vidKont_once_st":  $("#vidKont").val(),
                "date_once_st": $("#Date_Delivery").val(),
                "statement_once_st":  $("#number_of_list").val(),
                "type_once_st":  $("#tipv_once").val(),
                "number_points_once_st":  $("#mark_once").val(),
                "national_once_st":  $("#nac_shkala").val(),
                "ECTS_once_st":  $("#za_ECTS").val()
            },

            success: function (out) {

                alert('Дані оновилися');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Это poseschenie_zanyatiy.action.php

```
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax'] == 13 )
        {
              $USP1=$_POST["st_each"];
              $USP2=$_POST["semestr_once_st"];
              $USP3=$_POST["academicYear_once_st"];
              $USP4=$_POST["subject_once_st"];
              $USP5=$_POST["vidKont_once_st"];
              $USP6_100=$_POST["number_points_once_st"];
              $USP6=$_POST["national_once_st"];
              $USP6ECTS=$_POST["ECTS_once_st"];
              $USP7=$_POST["date_once_st"];
              $USP8=$_POST["lecturer_once_st"];
              $USP9=$_POST["type_once_st"];
              $USP10=$_POST["statement_once_st"];
              $id_line=$_POST["id"];
          if($result = $mysqli->query("
             UPDATE usp
              SET
              USP1='$USP1',
              USP2='$USP2',
              USP3='$USP3',
              USP4='$USP4',
              USP5='$USP5',
              USP6_100='$USP6_100',
              USP6='$USP6',
              USP6ECTS='$USP6ECTS',
              USP7='$USP7',
              USP8='$USP8',
              USP9='$USP9',
              USP10='$USP10'
              WHERE 
              id_line='$id_line'
             "))


          {

        echo("Дані обновилися");
        $mysqli->close() ;
          }

}
```

А это  модальное онко, где все происходит

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="edit_data_Modal"  tabindex="-1" 
role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">  
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">  
           <div class="modal-content"> 
               <form action="" method="post" id="update_form">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>  
                     <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Форма для корректування даних</h4>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body" id="update_details"> 
                                  <label>Рік навчання</label>
                <div>
                    <select name="academicYear" onchange="updateMinMax()" id="academicYear" class="form-control">
                        <option value="" selected="selected">--Оберіть рік навчання--</option>
                             <?  
                             select_year($mysqli);
                             ?>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <br>

                <label>Семестр</label>
                <div>
                    <select name="semestr" id="semestr" class="form-control">
                        <option value="0" selected>--Оберіть семестр--</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <br>
                <label >Дисципліна</label>
                <div>
                    <select name="subject" id="subject" class="form-control" >
                        <option value="0" selected="selected">--Оберіть дисципліну--</option>
                            <?php 
                            select_subj($mysqli);
                            ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <br>
                <label >Вид контролю знань</label>
                <div >
                    <select name="vidKont" id="vidKont"  class="form-control">
                           <option value="0" selected="selected">--Оберіть вид контролю знань--</option>
                            <?php 
                            select_type_of_control($mysqli);
                            ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <br>
                 <label>Викладач</label>
                <div>
                    <select name="lecturer" id="lecturer" class="form-control">

                        <option value="0" selected="selected">--Оберіть викладача--</option>
                            <?php 
                            select_lecture($mysqli);
                            ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <br>
                 <label>Тип відомості</label>
                 <div>
                     <select name="tipv_once" id="tipv_once" class="form-control">
                    <option value="0" selected="selected">--Оберіть тип відомості--</option>
                    <option value="Відомість">Відомість</option>
                    <option value="Хвостівка">"Хвостівка"</option>
                 </select>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                 <label>Номер відомості</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="number_of_list" id="number_of_list" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <br>
                <label>Дата складання дисципліни</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="date" name="Date_Delivery" min="" max="" value="" id="Date_Delivery" onblur="checkDate(this)" >
                </div>

                <br>
                <div class="row my-row">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="3" style="text-align:center;">Оцінка</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align:center;">Кількість балів</th>
                        <th>За національною шкалою</th>
                        <th>За шкалою ECTS</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <input type='text' class='USP6_100 form-control' name="mark_once" id="mark_once" style="text-align:center;" value=''/></td>

                    <td style="text-align:center;"><select class='USP6' name="nac_shkala" id="nac_shkala" disabled='true'>

                                    <option value='' selected></option>
                                    <option data-value='100' value='Відмінно'>Відмінно</option>
                                    <option data-value='89' value='Добре'>Добре</option>
                                    <option data-value='81' value='Добре'>Добре</option>
                                    <option data-value='74' value='Задовільно'>Задовільно</option>
                                    <option data-value='66' value='Задовільно'>Задовільно</option>
                                    <option data-value='59' value='Незадовільно'>Незадовільно</option>
                                    <option data-value='34' value='Незадовільно'>Незадовільно</option>
                                    <option data-value='0' value='Незадовільно'>Незадовільно</option>  
                            </select>
                    </td>

                    <td style="text-align:center;"><select class='USP6ECTS' id="za_ECTS" name="za_ECTS" disabled='true'>
                        <option value='' selected></option>
                                                <option>A</option>
                                                <option>B</option>
                                                <option>C</option>
                                                <option>D</option>
                                                <option>E</option>
                                                <option>Fx</option>
                                                <option>F</option>   
                            </select>
                            </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="st_id_edit" id="st_id_edit" />  
                 <input type="hidden" name="st_each" id="st_each" />         
                </div> 
                <div class="modal-footer">  
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Закрити</button> 
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary update_b" id="update">Зберегти зміни</button>  
                </div>  
                 </form> 
           </div>  
      </div>  
 </div>
```

Но в итоге данные в выбранное строке не обновляются, а удаляются после нажатии на кнопку обновить, в чем проблема, не могу вообще понять. Я все проверил:запрос правильный, данные все передаются с верным значением, я вообще не могу понять в чем проблема.Помогите пожалуйста любым советом.
дамб таблицы

```
    CREATE TABLE `usp` (
    `USP1` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `USP2` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `USP3` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `USP4` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `USP5` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `USP6_100` CHAR(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `USP6` TEXT NULL,
    `USP6ECTS` TEXT NULL,
    `USP7` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `USP8` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `USP9` CHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `USP10` CHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `id_line` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`USP1`, `USP2`, `USP4`, `USP5`),
    INDEX `id_line` (`id_line`),
    INDEX `FK_usp_uchgod` (`USP3`),
    INDEX `FK_usp_predm` (`USP4`),
    INDEX `FK_usp_vidkont` (`USP5`),
    INDEX `FK_usp_prep` (`USP8`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_usp_predm` FOREIGN KEY (`USP4`) REFERENCES `predm` (`predm1`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_usp_prep` FOREIGN KEY (`USP8`) REFERENCES `prep` (`PREP1`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_usp_st` FOREIGN KEY (`USP1`) REFERENCES `st` (`ST_ID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_usp_uchgod` FOREIGN KEY (`USP3`) REFERENCES `uchgod` (`uchgod1`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_usp_vidkont` FOREIGN KEY (`USP5`) REFERENCES `vidkont` (`id_vida_kontrolya`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=3721
;
```

Comment: Это не может делать то.

Comment: Это как понять ?

Comment: SQL запрос `"UPDATE ..."` не может удалять записи.

Comment: я понимаю, но это происходит

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте

1. Есть ли запись в базе до update
2. Точно ли у вас в поле st_id_edit есть ID

Comment: это я тоже проверил, и запись есть и id стоит, а его сделал не hidden, а text  и проверил, там все нормально, может быть это связано с PK, у меня их 4 просто. я добавил дамб сверху